# SELECT occupation from movie where year = 1950 AND rating =5 AND MAX(views);

Tags: mysql, sql, hive

I need help in solving this question. "in year 1950 which was the highest viewed  movie and 5 rating given user occupations for that movie, and which oocupation people viewed the movie a lot;"
I am getting the follow error
**"SemanticException [Error 10128]: Line 1:56 Not yet supported place for UDAF 'MAX'"**

```
movie_name, year, rating, occupation, views
A   1950    1   teacher 52
B   1953    5   doctor  45
C   1950    1   teacher 85
D   1952    4   police  35
E   1951    2   lawyer  15
F   1950    3   doctor  26
G   1951    1   lawyer  53
H   1952    2   teacher 85
I   1951    4   police  45
J   1950    3   doctor  36
K   1953    1   lawyer  52
L   1951    5   police  62
M   1953    2   teacher 42
N   1950    4   lawyer  85
O   1951    3   police  9
P   1952    1   doctor  44
Q   1950    5   teacher 27
R   1951    2   police  86
S   1955    3   lawyer  51
T   1950    5   police  49
U   1955    4   teacher 86
V   1954    3   lawyer  99
W   1951    2   teacher 84
X   1955    5   police  72
Y   1954    2   teacher 62
Z   1950    4   doctor  85
```

Comment: "in year 1950 which was the highest viewed movie and 5 rating given user occupations for that movie, and which oocupation people viewed the movie a lot;"  That makes no sense.

Comment: I'm guessing that this is a translation of the actual question

Comment: @strawberry, Yes you are right. I got this question from a blog

Comment: I believe the question is looking for the following: The name of the movie and made in 1950 that was the most viewed. Also, knowing the most viewed movie, which occupation viewed it the most.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an aggregate expression in the where clause; ordering the result should be sufficient.

```
SELECT movie_name, occupation, views
FROM movie
WHERE year = 1950 AND rating = 5
ORDER BY views DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I am getting this new error for the query which u provided. "SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 1:83 Invalid table alias or column reference 'views': (possible column names are: movie_name, occupation)"

Comment: i forgot to add views column in the select, check the edited sql

Comment: Now the query is functioning but it shows wrong answer 'Q'. If I remove the DESC then it shows the correct answer 'T'.  Why is that?

Comment: Do not remove the DESC, because it tell the MySQL to sort the result in descending order by column views so the first row is the one with the max views. I checked the query and it showed the correct answer!

Comment: Yeah according to logic you are right and it works fine for "select movie_name, occupation, views..." and it was giving wrong answer for "select movie_name, occupation views". It still accepted without ","  anyways--- Thanks Mahyar